# MyBatis & RefCursor Parameter

Tags: mybatis

Currently working on upgrading from iBatis to myBatis. In ibatis we would have a sql map like so

```
<resultMap id="PCRV_HIERARCHY_LVL_LIST_MAP" class="com.fmrco.sai.aadpm.domain.ConstraintHierarchyLevel">
    <result property="levelId" column="LEVEL_ID"/>
    <result property="levelDescription" column="LEVEL_DESCRIPTION"/>
    <result property="levelRank" column="LEVEL_RANK"/>
    <result property="levelCode" column="LEVEL_CODE"/>
</resultMap>

<parameterMap id="GET_HIERARCHY_LVL_LIST_MAP" class="java.util.Map">
    <parameter property="PCRV_HIERARCHY_LVL_LIST" jdbcType="ORACLECURSOR" javaType="java.sql.ResultSet" mode="OUT" resultMap="PCRV_HIERARCHY_LVL_LIST_MAP"/>
</parameterMap>


<procedure id="GET_HIERARCHY_LVL_LIST" parameterMap="GET_HIERARCHY_LVL_LIST_MAP">
    { call GET_HIERARCHY_LVL_LIST ( ? ) }
</procedure>
```

I'd like to fully utilize the functionality provided by myBatis (such as not needing to implement an implementation of a mapper and avoiding using deprecated features such as parameterMap) but I'm having some issues. I kept running into errors trying to set the return properties so I had to wrap my resultSet object in a wrapper object which is something I'd like to avoid

```
Mapper.java
public void getHierarchyLevels(ListConstraintHierarchyLevel constraintHierarchyLevels);
```

ConstraintHierarchyLevel class

```
public class ListConstraintHierarchyLevel {
    private List<ConstraintHierarchyLevel> constraintHierarchyLevels ;


    public List<ConstraintHierarchyLevel> getConstraintHierarchyLevels() {
        return constraintHierarchyLevels;
    }


    public void setConstraintHierarchyLevels(List<ConstraintHierarchyLevel> constraintHierarchyLevels) {
        this.constraintHierarchyLevels = constraintHierarchyLevels;
    }
}
```

mapper.xml

```
<resultMap id="HierarchyLvlMap" type="com.fmrco.sai.aadpm.domain.ConstraintHierarchyLevel">
    <result property="levelId" column="LEVEL_ID"/>
    <result property="levelDescription" column="LEVEL_DESCRIPTION"/>
    <result property="levelRank" column="LEVEL_RANK"/>
    <result property="levelCode" column="LEVEL_CODE"/>
</resultMap>

<select statementType="CALLABLE" 
    id="getHierarchyLevels" 
    parameterType="com.fmrco.sai.aadpm.domain.ListConstraintHierarchyLevel" 
    resultMap="HierarchyLvlMap">
    { call GET_HIERARCHY_LVL_LIST ( 
        #{constraintHierarchyLevels, 
        jdbcType=CURSOR,
        mode=OUT,
        javaType=java.sql.ResultSet,
        resultMap=HierarchyLvlMap}
     ) }
</select>
```

I have attempted another solution unsuccessfully. In this solution I make use of the param annotation

mapper.java

```
public void getHierarchyLevelsWithParam(@Param("constraintHierarchyLevels") List<ConstraintHierarchyLevel> constraintHierarchyLevels);
```

I use the same resultMap as above but with a different select block

mapper.xml

```
     <select statementType="CALLABLE" 
    id="getHierarchyLevelsWithParam" 
    parameterType="list" 
    resultMap="HierarchyLvlMap">
    { call GET_HIERARCHY_LVL_LIST ( 
        #{constraintHierarchyLevels, 
        jdbcType=CURSOR,
        mode=OUT,
        javaType=java.sql.ResultSet,
        resultMap=HierarchyLvlMap}
     ) }
```

When running this I have debugged into the MapperMethod class to the execute method and the Object param gets the correct data from the result set however as this does not get placed into the argument sent down (List) these values do not get returned. When running the first method with the object wrapper the objects are placed in the argument sent down and thus are retrievable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any other way than wrapping result object.
Indeed, the OUT variable has to be bound on something, this is a variable scope issue, then indirection is mandatory. But it can be generic:

```
class Wrapper<T> {
private List<T> member;
}
```

The @Param annotation is actually used to give parameters a name to uses as reference in the SQL (especially if the mapper method has multiple parameters)